# Get list of phrases contained in a both a string and Array

Tags: swift, string

Given a list:

```
let words = ["Apple", "the Banana", "Cherry"]
```

and a string:

```
let string = "The Apple was eaten before the Banana"
```

is it possible to easily get a list of phrases in the string that are in the array?

E.g. the result for the above would be:

```
let result = ["Apple", "the Banana"]
```

The follow is close, but only returns true or false:

```
let combinedResult = words.contains(where: string.contains)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my usecase, this took 27 seconds to run:

```
var words: [String] { Words.all.filter { self.contains($0) } }
```

whereas this took 1.5 seconds:

```
var words: [String] {

    var words = [String]()
    for word in self.components(separatedBy:" ") {

        if WordDictionary.all[word] != nil {
            words.append(word)
        }
    }
    return words
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter your array with the condition that it exists on the string like this:

```swift
let words = ["Apple", "the Banana", "Cherry"]
let string = "The Apple was eaten before the Banana"

print(words.filter { string.contains($0) }) // ["Apple", "the Banana"]
```

Comment: `words.filter(string.contains)` and for diacritics and case insensitive search `words.filter(string.localizedStandardContains)`

Comment: Thanks - this works but is incredibly inefficient/slow when you have a 3k words array and 50k strings - is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Do you use a database (CoreData, etc.) ? If so, you might want to do it in the request, instead of afterwards.